# LINQ .Where query takes 5+ minutes to execute

Tags: c#, .net, performance, linq

I need to filter a `List<object>` so that I remove any items where a `string` property does not exist inside another `List<string>`.

I created this console app just to make sure I had the LINQ syntax correct:

```
class FooBar
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ValueName { get; set; }
}
```

and then...

```
List<FooBar> foobars = new List<FooBar>
{
    new FooBar { Id = 1, ValueName = "Val1" },
    new FooBar { Id = 2, ValueName = "Val2" },
    new FooBar { Id = 3, ValueName = "Val3" },
    new FooBar { Id = 4, ValueName = "Val4" }
};

List<string> myStrings = new List<string>
{
    "Val1",
    "Val3"
};

// Only keep records where ValueName is found in `myStrings`
foobars = foobars.Where(f => myStrings.Contains(f.ValueName)).ToList();
```

So, this line:

```
foobars = foobars.Where(f => myStrings.Contains(f.ValueName)).ToList();
```

does exactly what I want, and it gives me back these two records:

```
{ Id = 1, ValueName = "Val1" }
{ Id = 3, ValueName = "Val3" }
```

All's well.  BUT... in the actual application, `foobars` has over 200k items, and `myStrings` has about 190k.  And when that LINQ line gets executed, it takes upwards of 5 minutes to complete.

I'm clearly doing something wrong. 200k records isn't THAT big. And the real `FooBar` isn't all that complex (no nested objects, and only 9 properties).

What's going on here?

Comment: Are both your list sorted? Asking because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-processing-an-unsorted-array)

Comment: If it's in-memory, that seems like a long time. If what you are actually doing is going to a database and using `Contains`, you're pulling back 190k records while avoiding using the database's indexes. Are you using a database?

Comment: Use `HashSet<string> myStrings` instead of `List<string>`

Comment: 2*4 is **almost** comparable to your actual code, which does 200K*190K string comparisons (38,000,000,000). Use a better data structure, like a HashSet.

Comment: @JustinLessard, nope, not sorted. I will sort them both and try again.

Comment: Hashset would be best and or using a join would work as well.

Comment: @ps2goat, yes, all in memory.

Comment: `foobars = (from foo in foobars
       join myString in myStrings
       on foo.ValueName equals myString
       select foo).ToList();` give that a shot as an alternative instead of doing a contains for every item.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ, thanks! I've already tested the answer below by Julian, and it worked wonderfully.

Comment: @CaseyCrookston I understand, you're welcome, I posted it as a comment as an alternative to *try* and compare. On another note, calling `ToList()` is a very time consuming routine as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is that you're doing `foobars.Where(f => myStrings.Contains(f.ValueName))` , so for every item in `foobars` your are checking **all** items of `myStrings`.

That scales quadratic. Also called O(n^2), read more [here](https://rob-bell.net/2009/06/a-beginners-guide-to-big-o-notation/). 
So if you have 10+10 items, you do 100  checks(10*10), and if you have 10,000+10,000 items, you will do 100,000,000 checks. 
In your case you're doing 38,000,000,000+ checks ;)

Solution: create a [HashSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1) from `myStrings` and use `Contains` of the `HashSet`.

e.g. replace with:

```cs
var myStringsSet = new HashSet<string>(myStrings);
foobars = foobars.Where(f => myStringsSet.Contains(f.ValueName)).ToList();
```

Now with 10,000+10,000 items, you will do 10,000 checks instead of 100,000,000. In your case that will 200,000 checks instead of 38,000,000,000.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Testing. I will return and report when testing is finished (it takes a few minutes)

Comment: Nailed it! Got the results I want in milliseconds.  Thank you!

Comment: Also, you must live in Europe? You're using . instead of , to separate thousands.

Comment: thanks, fixed the thousand operator. Cheers from the Netherlands ;)